# Como converter uma string inteira para caracteres maiúsculos sem usar laço?

Tags: c++, string, loop

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string nome = "pedro", up;
   
   for (int n = 0 ; n != nome.length(); n++) {
      up += toupper(nome[n]);
   }
   
   cout << "SEJA BEM-VINDO(A), " << up << endl;
   
   return 0;
}
```

Que gera a saída:

> ```
> SEJA BEM-VINDO(A), PEDRO
> ```

Existe uma função em C++ que converte uma string em maiúsculo sem a necessidade de ter que fazer um laço percorrer letra por letra usando o `toupper()` para converter os carácteres em maiúsculo, tal como feito no código acima?

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 3):

Não tem nada pronto, você tem que escrever o código, como fez (apesar de não ser uma ideia muito boa por questão de eficiência já que vai mudando o tamanho da *string*, mas que não afeta um exercício, mesmo isso não é crítico porque internamente é tratado de uma forma razoável, só não é a ideal, e é possível eliminar esse problema com a [devida inicialização](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)). Se puder mexer no próprio objeto original também pode fazer:

```
for (auto &letra: nome) letra = toupper(letra);
```

[Documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) e dos [iteradores](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin).

Ou

```
transform(nome.begin(), nome.end(), nome.begin(), ::toupper);
```

[Documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/Upper.cpp).

Ou da forma que achar mais conveniente para percorrer o texto. E pode criar uma função para usar depois quando precisar.